# HTTP Error 404.0 after installing 2sxc v9.33 on DNN 8.00.04

Tags: http, 2sxc

Installed 2sxc for the first time on a site. Immediately had problems with the 2sxc UI telling me 404 page not found. Switched to the server machine and IIS was showing the real error:
[image: screenshot]

I am not able to pin down the real issue. Anyone recognize this and know what the fix might be? Seems like a routing or permissions issue maybe?

IIS 7.5
DNN 8.00.04 patched
2sxc 9.33 (see screenshot for full)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're probably seeing is the full-screen iframe, but that's not loading for whatever reason. In the screenshot it looks like "ui.html" was stripped down to "ui?" so I'm guessing you have a server-side rewrite trying to protect html pages.

Comment: Yes, thanks for spotting that. We did have a rewrite (from 2016 that was completely forgotten) and just needed to add an exception in the web.config <rules> for .html in the 2sxc folder...
 
`<rule name="Pre-block (exclude) for 2sxc use of .html" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="DesktopModules/ToSIC_SexyContent" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
          <action type="None" />
</rule>`